# Get values from unlimted field programmatically in node_presave hook

Tags: 8, nodes

I have created class content type and set *Allowed number of values to **unlimited**"* to "Division" field
Now I want to get "Division" field values programmatically in node presave hook I'm using below code.

```
function example_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node){
  if($node->bundle() == "class") {
     $getDivison = $node->get('field_class_division')->target_id;
   }
}
```

If i print $getDivison then I get 739 only.
[image: Division field]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over a field object and access each item separately, that's often more convenient than going through getValue():

```
function example_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node){

  if($node->bundle() == "class") {
     foreach ($node->get('field_class_division') as $item) {
       echo $item->target_id;
     }
   }
}
```

And to access a specific delta (that's what the index in a multi-value field is called in the Field API), you can access it like an array as well, but you need to make sure that the deltas exist:

```
echo $node->get('field_class_division')[1]->target_id
```

See https://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet for a very useful cheat sheet on how to work with the Entity Field API.

Comment: Entity Cheatsheet link is dead and redirects to a different domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
function example_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node){

  if($node->bundle() == "class") {
     // Use getValue() to get multiple values in array.
     $getDivison = $node->get('field_class_division')->getValue();
   }
}
```

Comment: yeah, it's the perfect answer, you just need to  run a foreach loop the $getDivison variable, you could easily fetch the individual value.